# Kibana {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just set up authentication on a newly installed ES stack.
I followed:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/get-started-enable-security.html

I tried logging into kibana as user 'kibana'

I encountered `{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer:
Login as `elastic`
that simple

Comment: is that the anme you gave in your kibana.yml? @Jake

Comment: @SPishere, no, in kibana,yml you provide "kibana". That is why this setting confused me quite some hours!!! As I had 403 error for other reason, so never tried to use "elastic". Finally get it work.

Answer (score 0):

username : elastic

password : changeme `# or what ever password you kept while enabling xpack`